# YouTube Subscribe button/link without redirect

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, embed

I want to embed a youtube subscribe button in my webpage. But each time the subscribe button is clicked, it redirects the user to the YouTube app to subscribe.
I want the user to stay in my website, but let the user get a pop up window or something like that, to give access.

PS: this isn't a code request question. Just if someone points me in the right direction. I will figure it out. But if someone is willing to share any code, thanks for the help.